# SQL Server file version number: where can I find a reference?

Tags: sql-server

Summary: Where can I find a reference to SQL Server file version numbers?

Background: I'm moving a corporate website from a Win2003 Server with an install of SqlServer 2000 to a WinServer 2008 box with SqlServer 2008. I did the standard T-SQL "CREATE DATABASE" followed by "RESTORE DATABASE" commands and my database file imported, but I got a lot of info in the process I don't understand:

```
Processed 141992 pages for database 'WebsiteMain', file 'WebsiteMain' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'WebsiteMain', file 'WebsiteMain_log' on file 1.
Converting database 'WebsiteMain' from version 539 to the current version 655.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 539 to version 551.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 551 to version 552.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 552 to version 611.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 611 to version 621.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 621 to version 622.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 622 to version 625.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 625 to version 626.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 626 to version 627.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 627 to version 628.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 628 to version 629.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 629 to version 630.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 630 to version 631.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 631 to version 632.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 632 to version 633.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 633 to version 634.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 634 to version 635.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 635 to version 636.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 636 to version 637.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 637 to version 638.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 638 to version 639.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 639 to version 640.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 640 to version 641.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 641 to version 642.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 642 to version 643.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 643 to version 644.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 644 to version 645.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 645 to version 646.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 646 to version 647.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 647 to version 648.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 648 to version 649.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 649 to version 650.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 650 to version 651.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 651 to version 652.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 652 to version 653.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 653 to version 654.
Database 'WebsiteMain' running the upgrade step from version 654 to version 655.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 141994 pages in 141.262 seconds (7.852 MB/sec).
```

I can only presume the version numbers refer to something of significance inside of SqlServer, but I'm having trouble believing that there have been *that* many releases/patches/upgrades to SqlServer since 2000. Moreover, I don't recall ever seeing SQL Server version numbers expressed in three digits in the ranges indicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jonathan Kehayias in his blog quotes the following version numbers:

SQL Server 7.0 databases have version number 515 
SQL Server 2000 databases have version number 539 
SQL Server 2005 databases have version number 611/612 
SQL Server 2008 databases have version number 655

Jonathan's blog:
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-13-difference-between-database-version-and-database-compatibility-level/

Comment: Perfect -- exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-20-Boot-pages-and-boot-page-corruption.aspx) , who should know, this is the physical version number of the database.  See the first question in this [TechNet magazine link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.sqlqa.aspx)

Kev

Edit:

you can get similar info by running

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604); 
GO
DBCC DBINFO('databasename')
GO
```

I'm still looking for a definitive list though........

Answer (score 0):

It's not unreasonable to say there are 110 differences between the SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2000 database formats.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest why did you create the database? Couldn’t you simply restore it?

Comment: Somewhere between old habits and bad habits, I found then when I'm moving a DB from serverA to serverB it always just worked if step 1 was "CREATE DATABASE Umptysquat" followed by "RESTORE DATABASE Umptysquat.... WITH REPLACE". Once I discovered that this worked I happily when back into Visual Studio to write more code and left the discussion of how perfect that solution was (or wasn't) to the DBAs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query SQL to have a list of your current databases with file version and compatibility level, here is how:

```
SELECT name, version, cmptlevel, filename FROM master.sys.sysdatabases
```