# How do I convert a SQL Server 2008 .mdf file to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to convert a file `DATABASE.MDF` from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012?

> Database 'Sales' cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (539) is not supported by this version of SQL Server. You cannot open a database that is incompatible with this version of sqlservr.exe. You must re-create the database.
>   Could not open new database 'Sales'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 950)

Comment: you don't need conversion of it. Just restore it directly on sql server 2012.

Comment: Thank for you time, but I have the next error: Database 'Sales' cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (539) is not supported by this version of SQL Server. You cannot open a database that is incompatible with this version of sqlservr.exe. You must re-create the database.
Could not open new database 'Sales'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 950) ..................                                 and honestly I found several solutions, but without success

Comment: Please see the update to my answer. You know there is a big difference between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008. Not describing your problem accurately is a good way to get a bunch of useless advice and wasting people's time in the process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just attach it and it will be upgraded. If you don't have the LDF file (and why don't you have the LDF file?) you may have to use:

```
CREATE DATABASE [DatabaseName] ON 
    (FILENAME = N'Drive:\path\file.mdf')
    FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

There are some caveats, of course...

- seeing as you only have the .mdf file, you may possibly be in for a rude awakening. If the file was not cleanly detached from SQL Server, it may not be re-attachable, and you will have to go back to the source server for a *proper* backup (not an .mdf file). This will all depend on where you got the .mdf file you're trying to upgrade. If your .mdf file was not cleanly detached, you may get this error:

> File activation failure. The physical file name "..._log.LDF" may be incorrect.
>   The log cannot be rebuilt because the database was not cleanly shut down.
>   Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Could not open new database 'DatabaseName'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

- if your database is in 80 compatibility mode, it will be upgraded to 90. This may mean some working code may suddenly break, such as `*=`/`=*` join syntax.
- if your database is > 10GB and you try attaching to Express (and maybe LocalDB, have never tried this), the attach will fail (or maybe the attach succeeds but will fail at the first autogrow? Have not tested this either).
- you will also have issues if your database was created on 2008 Enterprise / Developer and you used features only available there, and you attach the database to Standard or Express editions...
- OK, from your error message, you are not trying to attach a 2008 database at all, but rather a 2000 database. You cannot attach this directly to SQL Server 2012. You will first need to attach it to any instance of SQL Server 2005, 2008 or 2008 R2 to upgrade it to that version, and then back it up and restore it to SQL Server 2012.

FWIW, a much, much, much safer way of moving a database from one instance to another is using `BACKUP`/`RESTORE` (the reason is that if your backup fails, you still have a copy of the database - if you detach a database, and something goes wrong, you have zero copies). Though some of the issues above may still apply even with this safer approach.

Comment: thanks for the info.... and now.. Could not open new database 'Sales'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
Msg 950, Level 20, State 1, Line 1
Database 'Sales' cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (539) is not supported by this version of SQL Server. You cannot open a database that is incompatible with this version of sqlservr.exe. You must re-create the database.

How could solve the problem?

Comment: Did you *read my update*, the last bullet point that starts with `OK`? You ***cannot attach this database to SQL Server 2012***. You need to attach it to 2005, 2008 or 2008 R2 *first*, then back it up and restore it to 2012. Stop trying. None of the other methods are going to work - this is intentionally blocked by SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem, just to point OK .. I apologize I had tried so many options and had little time and a lot of pressure, but I would not have done it without your help   Solution:backup/restore

Answer (score 2):

The OP seems to have been mistaken about his DB type. Version 539 of SQL Server is not 2008 but SQL Server 2000. See this thread:
[SQL Server file version number: where can I find a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104221/sql-server-file-version-number-where-can-i-find-a-reference)

I've run into this same error message trying to attach/restore a SQL Server 2000 db to an instance of SQL Server 2012. Perhaps there was a way around it, but what I did instead was first convert to SQL Server 2008 R2, and then to SQL Server 2012. This executed with no trouble.

Comment: how did you convert it to 2012 version. Is there any tool?

Comment: Actually I do not recall off-hand if I restored from .bak or was simply attaching and detaching a database.
I had both 2008R2 and 2012 instances on my machine, so I just attached/restored to the 2008 instance, then detached/backed-up and attached/restored to the 2012 instance.